# "Can't install libgconf-2-4 (3.2.6-2ubuntu1)" while trying to install Spotify

Tags: dependencies, spotify, gconf

I'm trying to install Spotify but and it leads me to this error.

[image: Break existing package 'gconf-service-backend' dependency libgconf-2-4 ( = 3.2.6-2ubuntu1)]

Any solution to this?

Comment: Follow this guide http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/01/how-to-install-spotify-in-ubuntu-12-04-12-10

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to install Spotify, try the following commands: 
Press Ctrl+Alt+T to launch the terminal, paste these commands on the terminal (Ctrl+Shift+V) and hit Enter.

Add the Spotify repository signing key to be able to verify downloaded packages

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys BBEBDCB318AD50EC6865090613B00F1FD2C19886
```

Add the Spotify repository

```
echo deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list
```

Update list of available packages

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install Spotify

```
sudo apt-get install spotify-client
```

Download and install libcrypt

```
wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/libg/libgcrypt11/libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i libgcrypt11_1.5.0-5+deb7u3_amd64.deb
```

If it does not work, uninstall Spotify

```
sudo apt-get purge spotify*
```

And start from step 1.

If it still doesn't work, then you might need to run the following commands. Beware this will ***delete configuration files***. Assuming this is Gnome 3:

```
rm -rf .gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity .cache .dbus .dmrc .mission-control .thumbnails ~/.config/dconf/user ~.compiz*
```

You can back up and reset configuration files with:

```
mkdir ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.gnome* ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv .gconf* ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.metacity ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.cache ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.dbus ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.dmrc ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.mission-control ./.old-gnome-config/ && mv ./.thumbnails ./.old-gnome-config/   && mv ~/.config/dconf/* ./.old-gnome-config/
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the thing is this.  I have followed the instructions on spotify website, just like your instruction, but whenever I get to step 4, this error happens in the terminal
**The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 spotify-client : Depends: libgconf2-4 but it is not installable
                  Depends: libnss3-1d but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.** 

then whenever I try to install the dependencies required, as you can see  the image in my question, that is whats happening

Answer (score 0):

You need to install these two packages :

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gconf/libgconf-2-4_3.2.6-8_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gconf/gconf2-common_3.2.6-8_all.deb
sudo dpkg - i *.deb
```

where `*` represent the files you have downloaded